# setMinDate of a DatePicker from another DatePicker

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I'm developing an app for a hotel (personal learning project). In the "Book Now" page I'm displaying 2 `EditText` fields. One for Check-in Date and another for Check-Out Date.

I've set the `DatePicker` to only display current and future dates using the `setMinDate()`. But what I want is that the Check-out `DatePicker` should display (Check-in Date + 1) as selectable dates.

So for example, if the user selects the check-in date as 24/10/2017, the check-out `DatePicker` should display the dates from 25/10/2017.

BookFragment.java

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    EditText inDate = v.findViewById(R.id.checkInDate);
    inDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DateDialog dialog = new DateDialog(view);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            dialog.show(ft, "Select Check-In Date");
        }
    });

    EditText outDate = v.findViewById(R.id.checkOutDate);
    outDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText inDateText = v.findViewById(R.id.checkInDate);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(inDateText.getText().toString())) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Select Check-in Date first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                DateDialog dialog = new DateDialog(view);
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                dialog.show(ft, "Select Check-Out Date");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

DateDialog.java

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class DateDialog extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

EditText dateText;
int cyear, cmonth, cday;

public DateDialog(View view) {
    dateText = (EditText) view;
}

@NonNull
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    DatePickerDialog date = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, cyear, cmonth, cday);
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date currentDate = c.getTime();
    cyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    cmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    cday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    date.getDatePicker().setMinDate(currentDate.getTime());
    return date;

}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    String date = day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year;
    dateText.setText(date);
}
```

book.xml

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/checkInDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint="@string/check_in_date"
        android:inputType="date" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/checkOutDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint="@string/check_out_date"
        android:inputType="date" />
```

Since both the EditText are calling the same DateDialog class, how can I get the check-in date and use it to setMinDate() for check-out?

Right now, what I'm doing as a workaround is getting the date string from EditText, parsing it into a Date and doing the same for check-out. When the user clicks the "Book" button, it checks whether the check-out is earlier than check-in using

```
if (odate.before(idate)) {
        outDateText.setError("Check-Out must be after Check-In");
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Check-Out Date must be after Check-In Date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        flag = 1;
    }
```

This does the work, but I would rather have disabled dates which are before check-in date.

Comment: are you getting any error

Comment: @UltimateDevil No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your **`Date`** is

```
String string_date = "24/10/2017";
```

then, increase one day to your current date

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.setTime(string_date); 
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
checkOutDate = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

then set `minDate` to your `datePicker`

```
datePicker.setMinDate(checkOutDate - 1000);
```

**EDIT**

create a `global` `long` variable `dateToSet` in your **`DateDialog`** class

like - `long dateToSet;`

change your `constructor` from

```
public DateDialog(View view) {
dateText = (EditText) view;
}
```

to

```
public DateDialog(View view, long dateToSet) {
dateText = (EditText) view;
//then update the value of dateToSet here
this.dateToSet = dateToSet
}
```

then for your **`Editext 1`** use this

```
else {
            Date currentDate = c.getTime();
            cyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            cmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            cday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DateDialog dialog = new DateDialog(view,currentDate.getTime());
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            dialog.show(ft, "Select Check-Out Date");
        }
```

for your **`Editext 2`** use this

```
//String string_date = "24/10/2017";
//getting current date from editText 1
String string_date = editText.getText().toString();
//check the string must not be null
//then, increase one day to your current date

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.setTime(string_date); 
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
checkOutDate = cal.getTimeInMillis();
DateDialog dialog = new DateDialog(view,checkOutDate);
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            dialog.show(ft, "Select Check-Out Date");
```

Then your **`onCreateDialog`** must be

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

DatePickerDialog date = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, cyear, cmonth, cday);
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
date.getDatePicker().setMinDate(dateToSet);
return date;

}
```

may help you

Comment: Yes, but how to get and use the string for check-out DatePicker as both EditText are calling the same DateDialog class?

Comment: then create another one

Comment: first get the string from edittext then save this to a string then

Comment: second create a another DatePicker

Comment: In the  onCreateDialog I get the following error: Cannot resolve symbol 'dateToSet'

Comment: Wait @ParthSarthi I am updating your solution again

Comment: @ParthSarthi see the change you have to create a variable in class as mentioned above in edited answer